# How can I sort my product attributes in excel for magento import

Tags: excel, magento, excel-formula, vlookup

basically I run a Magento store with various clothing products. I need to somehow use excel so I can input my product name, SKU and attributes, to generate a Magento csv import file.

I have many attributes such as Colour, Leg Size, Waist Size.

For example, one product may have the following potential attributes

Cargo Trousers -

Colours: Black, Navy, Khaki

Leg Size: 31, 33, 35

Waist: 32, 34, 36 , 38, 40, 42

I need to somehow setup a loop that can take the values and arrange them in the following format

Colour|   LegSize|   Waist|

Black  |    31|        34|

Black  |    31|        36|

Black  |    31|        38|

etc.

I hope I made it clear. This product for example would have over 54 variations.

I literally want to be able to input the variations and have excel do the hard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a recursive function call, rather than a loop?

Here is how I structured my data to answer your question (I don't yet have enough rep to post a picture, so here's a diagram of the table I used:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|   |       A        |    B     |   C   |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1 | Cargo Trousers |          |       |
|---------------------------------------|
| 2 | Colours        | Leg Size | Waist |
|---------------------------------------|
| 3 | Black          | 31       | 32    |
|---------------------------------------|
| 4 | Navy           | 33       | 34    |
|---------------------------------------|
| 5 | Khaki          | 35       | 36    |
|---------------------------------------|
| 6 |                |          | 38    |
|---------------------------------------|
| 7 |                |          | 40    |
|---------------------------------------|
| 8 |                |          | 42    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Here's a chunk of code that you can use to get the list you wanted.  Please note that it's looking for empty cells, so don't skip.  :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim HomeSheet As String
Dim NewSheet As String

Function GetAllPermutations()

    HomeSheet = ActiveSheet.Name 'Where we start from
    NewSheet = Sheets.Add.Name 'Place to put new stuff
    Sheets(HomeSheet).Select

    RecursivePermutations "", 1, 0

End Function

Function RecursivePermutations(ByVal CurrentValue As String, ByVal SourceColumn As Long, ByRef OutputRow As Long)

    Dim x As Long
    Dim myText As String

    For x = 3 To Cells.Rows.Count

        'Is this row's value empty?  Then we need to exit
        If Cells(x, SourceColumn) = "" Then
            If x = 3 Then
                'We hit a brand new blank column, time to write it out
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                Sheets(NewSheet).Cells(OutputRow, 1) = CurrentValue
            End If
            'All done here
            Exit Function
        End If

        If SourceColumn = 1 Then
            'First time through loop for this base value
            myText = Trim(Cells(x, SourceColumn))
        Else
            'Add another one
            myText = "|" & Trim(Cells(x, SourceColumn))
        End If

        'Make recursive call to self
        RecursivePermutations CurrentValue & myText, SourceColumn + 1, OutputRow

    Next x

End Function
```